# How to add the opacities to a set of colors?

Tags: color

Consider a set of colors in the LAB color space.

```
lab = {LABColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.8], LABColor[0.6, -0.5, 0.2], 
  LABColor[0.9, 0.5, -0.8]};
```

And the corresponding opacities are

```
a={0.2,0.6,0.4};
```

How can I combine the colors and their corresponding opacities so that I get

```
laba={LABColor[0.2, 0.5, 0.8,0.2], LABColor[0.6, -0.5, 0.2,0.6], 
  LABColor[0.9, 0.5, -0.8,0.4]}
```

Comment: Look up `MapThread`.  `MapThread[Append, {lab, a}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
MapThread[Append, {lab, a}]
```